# Parsing error using Minted Cucumber escapeinside containing number

Tags: minted

I'm trying to use Minted to perform syntax highlighting of Cucumber code in LaTeX. I want to use `escapeinside` to color Cucumber parameters, since they depend on definitions and can't be automatically highlighted by the parser without additional information. However, If an escapeinside sequence contains a number, the escapeinside delimiter is getting marked as a syntax error, thus this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[gobble=0,escapeinside=||]{cucumber}
Feature: Invented example
  Scenario: Check the results
    Given |1|
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

produces this output (unaltered):

[image: Syntax-highlighted Cucumber code from the MWE. The pipe characters are present, and appear with a red box.]

The pipe characters, which should not be displayed at all, are shown, and are marked with red boxes indicating a syntax error. What is going on here, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around the issue by setting the number in a macro and referencing the macro within the escapeinside:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\one}{1}
\begin{minted[gobble=0,escapeinside=||]{cucumber}
Feature: Invented example
  Scenario: Check the results
    Given |\one|
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 could you accept this answer please if you answered your own question, it'll keep getting bumped by the `community` bot otherwise :)

Comment: @JamesT Alas, I was hoping for a better answer; mine is far from ideal. However, since no other seems to be forthcoming, I've accepted this one for now.